# Add text to config file and use it in code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aes

I am using AES encryption and generating a random salt, I am storing this random salt in the database.. Before I store the value to the database I want to append a string to it. I want this string to be placed in config file. How can I store a string in config file and How can I call in to append it with my salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="specialstring" value="value to append" />
</appSettings>
```

and access this by <strike>ConfigurationSettings</strike>`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["specialstring"]` and append

Also you can use 
[`WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) in the same way instead of <strike>ConfigurationSettings</strike>`ConfigurationManager`

Comment: I am getting this error: Non-invocable member 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: oops need to use square brackets

Comment: string strServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["specialstring"]; I solved it

Comment: `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is obsolete, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553246/add-text-to-config-file-and-use-it-in-code-behind-in-asp-net/7553348#7553348)

Answer (score 1):

Set value in web-config file by below code snippet

```
<appSettings><add key="KeyForValue" value="ValueString" /></appSettings>
```

Get value in coding file by below code snippet

```
string strValuetoGet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyForValue"]
```

Comment: `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is obsolete, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553246/add-text-to-config-file-and-use-it-in-code-behind-in-asp-net/7553348#7553348)

Answer (score 0):

put the string in the appSettings section of your web.config file, something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key="mySaltPrefix" value="your value..." />
  ...
</appSettings>
```

then read it from your C# code in this way:

```
var mySaltPrefix = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySaltPrefix"];
```

to run this code you should add a reference to System.Configuration to your C# project.